# UITableView throws EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when user tries to scroll to reveal lower rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

My `UITableView` is displaying correctly without a hitch. However, it crashes with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` whenever the user tries to scroll down to reveal the bottom rows. I have already tried commenting out every `[someobject release]` but to no avail. I suspect the culprit is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Here is the code for my entire controller :

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {

    NSLog(@"myString is :%@", myString);
    int processID = [myString intValue];

    //NSLog(@"transferredArray is %@", transferredArray);
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps"];

    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"aux", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", processID],nil];

    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                                   encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"ps aux output :%@",string);


    NSArray *lines= [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSString *lastline = [lines objectAtIndex:[lines count]-2];
    //  NSLog(@"%@",lastline);



    lines2= [lastline componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%@",lines2);
    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }


    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""""]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"0.0"]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"??"]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

        if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"0:00.00"]){
            [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }

    NSLog(@"lines2 after for loops is %@", lines2);









    NSLog(@"Lines 2 is%@",lines2);



    self.title = @"Process Info";

    label = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [label addObject:@"User:"];
    [label addObject:@"Process ID:"];
    [label addObject:@"CPU(%):"];
    [label addObject:@"MEM(%):"];
    [label addObject:@"Status:"];
    [label addObject:@"Time Started:"];
    [label addObject:@"Launch Path:"];
    [label addObject:@"STAT:"];
    [label addObject:@"Time Started:"];
    [label addObject:@"Time Elapsed:"];
    [label addObject:@"Launch Command:"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


/*
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
 */


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   


    /*
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFromat:@"Cell_%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
    */
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
    NSString *cellValue = [label objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    cell.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:154.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];


    UILabel *label2 =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 0, 240.0, 
                                                                  tableView.rowHeight)]autorelease]; 




    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]; 
    NSString *cellValue1 = [lines2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label2.text = cellValue1;
    label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
    label2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    label2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label2]; 


    return cell;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [lines2 count];
}


- (void)dealloc 
{
    //[transferredArray release];
    //[myString release];
    //[arguments release];
    //[ResultStringID release];
    //[values release];
    //[label release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will help:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   

UILabel *label2;
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
    cell.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:154.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

    label2 =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 0, 240.0, 
                                                         tableView.rowHeight)]autorelease];

    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]; 
    NSString *cellValue1 = [lines2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label2.text = cellValue1;
    label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
    label2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    label2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label2]; 

}


NSString *cellValue = [label objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
}
```

because you tablecell is dequeueble so you shoulden't init label if cell is not nil. only change text of the label when tableview is updated (or init everything if cell is nil)

Comment: Thanks bro! +1 for pasting the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method :)